# Access Composite key in Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following tables with relationship ManyToMany

Task Table:

```
 [TASK_ID] pk
    ,[TASK_NAME]
```

Option Table:

```
[OPTION_ID] pk
      ,[OPTION_VALUE]
```

and the task_options Table which contain composite primary key from the two foreign keys of the previous tables

```
[TASK_ID]
      ,[OPTION_ID]
```

and it's Mapping as follow:

```
Task_Options.java
@Entity
@Table(name = "TASK_OPTIONS")
public class Task_Options implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private pk pk;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("Task_ID")
    private Task task;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("Option_ID")
    private Options options;

    public Task getTask() {
        return task;
    }

    public void setTask(Task task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    public Options getOptions() {
        return options;
    }

    public void setOptions(Options options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    /*Inner Class for Composite primary key*/
    @Embeddable
    public static class pk implements Serializable {

        private int Task_ID;        
        private int Option_ID;

        public pk(int Task_ID, int Option_ID) {
            this.Task_ID = Task_ID;
            this.Option_ID = Option_ID;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            int hash = 7;
            hash = 47 * hash + this.Task_ID;
            hash = 47 * hash + this.Option_ID;
            return hash;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj) {
                return true;
            }
            if (obj == null) {
                return false;
            }
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
                return false;
            }
            final pk other = (pk) obj;
            if (this.Task_ID != other.Task_ID) {
                return false;
            }
            if (this.Option_ID != other.Option_ID) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

i want create hibernate criteria to execute the following query

```
 select OPTION_VALUE from [dbo].[OPTION] AS op                      
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[TASK_OPTIONS] AS TSOP ON op.OPTION_ID = TSOP.OPTION_ID 
  INNER JOIN [dbo].[TASK] AS tsk ON tsk.TASK_ID = TSOP.TASK_ID
  Where Tsk.TASK_ID = 2
```

i have tried this

```
                Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Task_Options.class, "Tsop");
                criteria.createAlias("Tsop.Task_ID", "task");
                criteria.createAlias("Tsop.Option_ID", "op");
                criteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("Tsop.task.Task_ID", "task.task_ID"));
                criteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("Tsop.options.Option_ID", "op.option_ID"));
```

not working because of Task_ID of Task_options cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need `@EmbeddedId private pk pk;`. Hibernate can resolve Objects mapped to ids.

Can you try with this criteria?

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Task_Options.class, "Tsop");
criteria.createAlias("task", "task");
criteria.createAlias("options", "op");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("task.task_id", 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to type join.I will give an example with my own application.

Employee.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="EMPLOYEE" )
public class Employee implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column
private String firstName;
@Column
private int salary;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Address address;
}
```

Address.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="ADDRESS" )
public class Address implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column
private String city;
@Column
private String zipcode;
}
```

Main.class:

```
    private static void list4() {
    try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) 
    {
        Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Employee.class, "employee");
        c.createAlias("employee.address", "address");
        c.setFetchMode("address", FetchMode.JOIN);
        c.add(Restrictions.isNotNull("firstName"));
        c.add(Restrictions.like("address.zipcode", "%zipcode%"));
        c.add(Restrictions.like("address.city", "%city%"));
        List<?> results = c.list();
        results.forEach(s -> System.out.println(s.toString()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```